# Dagger2- Retrofit is not injecting in ApiHelperImpl

Tags: android, kotlin, dagger-2, dagger

Hi I am trying to inject `retrofit` in `ApiHelperImpl.kt` class. I have below module and component.

AppComponent.kt

```
@Component(modules = arrayOf(AndroidInjectionModule::class, AppModule::class, ActivityBuilder::class))
@Singleton
interface AppComponent {
    fun inject(app: PartnerApplication)
}
```

AppModule.kt

```
@Module
class AppModule {

    @Provides
    @Singleton
    fun providesPartnerApplication(application: Application): Application = application

    @Provides
    @Singleton
    fun providesSharedPreferences(application: Application): SharedPreferences {
        return PreferenceManager.getDefaultSharedPreferences(application)
    }

    @Provides
    @Singleton
    fun provideOkHttpCache(application: Application): Cache {
        val cacheSize = 10 * 1024 * 1024L // 10 MiB
        return Cache(application.cacheDir, cacheSize)
    }

    @Provides
    @Singleton
    fun provideMoshi(): Moshi = Moshi.Builder().build()

    @Provides
    @Singleton
    fun provideOkHttpClient(cache: Cache): OkHttpClient {
        val okHttpClient = OkHttpClient()
        okHttpClient.newBuilder()
                .cache(cache)
                .build()
        return okHttpClient
    }

    @Provides
    @Singleton
    fun provideRetrofit(moshi: Moshi, okHttpClient: OkHttpClient): Retrofit {
        return Retrofit.Builder()
                .addConverterFactory(MoshiConverterFactory.create(moshi))
                .baseUrl(BuildConfig.BASE_URL)
                .client(okHttpClient)
                .build()
    }

}
```

PartnerApplication.kt

```
class PartnerApplication : Application(), AnkoLogger, HasActivityInjector {

    @Inject lateinit var activityInjector: DispatchingAndroidInjector<Activity>

    override fun activityInjector(): AndroidInjector<Activity> {
        return activityInjector
    }

    override fun onCreate() {
        super.onCreate()
        DaggerAppComponent.create().inject(this)
    }

    override protected fun attachBaseContext(base: Context) {
        super.attachBaseContext(base)
        MultiDex.install(this)
    }

}
```

ApiHelper.kt

```
interface ApiHelper {
    fun doServerLoginApiCall(email: String, password: String): Observable<LoginResponse>
    fun doServerRegistrationApiCall(): Observable<RegistrationResponse>
}
```

ApiHelperImpl.kt

```
class ApiHelperImpl : ApiHelper {

    @Inject
    lateinit var retrofit: Retrofit

    override fun doServerLoginApiCall(email: String, password: String): Observable<LoginResponse> {
        return retrofit.create(RestApi::class.java).login(email, password)
    }

    override fun doServerRegistrationApiCall(): Observable<RegistrationResponse> {
        TODO("not implemented") //To change body of created functions use File | Settings | File Templates.
    }
}
```

LoginActivity.kt

```
class LoginActivity : BaseActivity() {

    @Inject
    lateinit var loginViewModel: LoginViewModel

    override fun onCreate(savedInstanceState: Bundle?) {
        performDependencyInjection()
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState)
        val activityLoginBinding: ActivityLoginBinding = DataBindingUtil.setContentView<ActivityLoginBinding>(this, R.layout.activity_login)
        activityLoginBinding.loginViewModel = loginViewModel
    }
}
```

LoginViewModel.kt

```
class LoginViewModel : ViewModel(), AnkoLogger {

    val emailField = ObservableField<String>()

    private val email: String
        get() = emailField.get()

    val passwordField = ObservableField<String>()

    private val password: String
        get() = passwordField.get()

    val progressVisibility: ObservableInt = ObservableInt(View.GONE)

    @Suppress("PARAMETER_NAME_CHANGED_ON_OVERRIDE")
    fun login(view: View) {
        if (isEmailAndPasswordValid(email, password))
            ApiHelperImpl().doServerLoginApiCall(email, password)
                    .subscribeOn(Schedulers.io())
                    .observeOn(AndroidSchedulers.mainThread())
                    .subscribeWith(object : CallbackWrapper<LoginResponse>() {

                        override fun onSuccess(loginResponse: LoginResponse) {
                        }
                    })

    }

    /**
     * Validate email and password. It checks email and password is empty or not
     * and validate email address is correct or not
     * @param email email address for login
     * @param password password for login
     * @return true if email and password pass all conditions else false
     */
    private fun isEmailAndPasswordValid(email: String, password: String): Boolean {

        if (email.isEmpty()) return false

        if (!Patterns.EMAIL_ADDRESS.matcher(email).matches()) return false

        if (password.isEmpty()) return false

        return true
    }

}
```

LoginActivityModule.kt

```
@Module
class LoginActivityModule {

    @Provides
    fun providesLoginActivityViewModel(): LoginViewModel {
        return LoginViewModel()
    }
}
```

ActivityBuilder.kt

```
@Module
abstract class ActivityBuilder {

    @ContributesAndroidInjector(modules = arrayOf(LoginActivityModule::class))
    abstract fun bindLoginActivity(): LoginActivity

}
```

I am getting an error

```
Process: com.partner.android, PID: 9697
kotlin.UninitializedPropertyAccessException: lateinit property retrofit has not been initialized
    at com.partner.android.data.remote.ApiHelperImpl.doServerLoginApiCall(ApiHelperImpl.kt:32)
    at com.partner.android.login.LoginViewModel.login(LoginViewModel.kt:45)
    at com.partner.android.databinding.ActivityLoginBinding$OnClickListenerImpl.onClick(ActivityLoginBinding.java:298)
    at android.view.View.performClick(View.java:5637)
    at android.view.View$PerformClick.run(View.java:22429)
    at android.os.Handler.handleCallback(Handler.java:751)
    at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:95)
    at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:154)
    at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:6119)
    at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Native Method)
    at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(ZygoteInit.java:886)
    at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:776)
```

Why `retrofit` is not injecting in ApiHelperImpl class.

Comment: You need to call `component.inject(this)` in the `ApiHelperImpl` class

Comment: @Héctor Where I should call `component.inject(this)`

Comment: @Williams, can you post a simple project with that behavior at github?

Comment: @azizbekian I think this is all I have in my code related to dagger

Comment: @azizbekian can you please suggest if you think something is missing

Comment: As I said, if you upload a simple project at github, I'll have a look.

Comment: @azizbekian please see here https://www.dropbox.com/s/z3pquzr2jc159xy/android.zip?dl=0

Comment: @Williams, that doesn't look like a valid android project, it's just a bunch of files. Can you post a project, that can be imported into Android Studio and reproduced your issue?

Comment: @azizbekian I see but it has very large codebase and confidential, can you create project and put these classes. I am creating `retrofit` inside `ApiHelperImpl.kt` where I am getting an error

Answer (score 1, accepted):

in order to use `@Inject` in `ApiHelperImpl` you have to add it (calling `inject` on the component) to the dependency graph. In this case I would pass it as dependency to the constructor of `ApiHelperImpl`

```
  class ApiHelperImpl @Inject constructor(val retrofit : Retrofit) : ApiHelper {

     val mRetrofit = retrofit
```

should do it

Comment: I am calling it `ApiHelperImpl` from the `LoginViewModel` what to pass here ? like `ApiHelperImpl().doServerLoginApiCall(email, password)`

Comment: Do you mean this `class LoginViewModel @Inject constructor(val retrofit: Retrofit) : AnkoLogger {`

Comment: check [this](https://github.com/bblackbelt/BreweryApp/tree/develop/app/src/main/java/com/blackbelt/brewery/di) out

Comment: Thanks. I am getting this error: dagger.internal.codegen.ComponentProcessor was unable to process this interface because not all of its dependencies could be resolved

Comment: e: public abstract interface AppComponent {
e:                 ^

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/159073/discussion-between-williams-and-blackbelt).

Comment: here you can see https://chat.stackoverflow.com/transcript/message/40043912#40043912

Comment: Did you get a chance to look

Comment: It worked, I made one variable private, so it was the issue. Now I want to create instance of `ApiHelperImpl` to call `doServerLoginApiCall` how should i do in loginviewmodel

Comment: Ok thank you will try today, btw why it is constructor injection here ?

Comment: Well, I guess you want dagger to instante the VM for you. When you inject it, Android will be resolve the dependency(ies) for you. If VM is part of the life cycle extensions, then you are probably using the ViewModelProvider from the sdk. If that's the case you will need a custom factory. I'll provide an example in few hours if you need it

Comment: I am doing it like this in `LoginActivity ` class `private val loginViewModel: LoginViewModel by lazy {
        ViewModelProviders.of(this).get(LoginViewModel::class.java)
    }` so here it will inject all dependencies which are in the constructor of loginviewmodel right ?

Comment: ok. just for learning what changes I need to make if I want to inject like this    `@Inject
    lateinit var apiHelper : ApiHelper` ? in loginviewmodel

Comment: to inject that one in your Activity, you don't have to change anything.

Comment: something like [this](https://gist.github.com/bblackbelt/8cd5ec78ab2a5150a1f72606ce22a365) should do it

Comment: I tried suggested solution, I am getting this error https://pastebin.com/FvdhJSYL can you look please

Comment: As usual some code would help. Btw yesterday I pushed some VMs on the same repository. Very close to what your are trying right now. Give it a try!

Comment: Thank you so much. It worked :)  I am getting this error https://pastebin.com/aqLVkMby and code here https://pastebin.com/QhJH1Gbr can you have a look pls

Comment: `ViewModelProviders.of(this).get(LoginViewModel::class.java)` should be `ViewModelProviders.of(this, mFactory).get(LoginViewModel::class.java)`

Answer (score 2):

You can implement the same using module

```
@Module
class ApiModule {


@Provides
@Singleton
fun apiService(context: Context): WebService {
    val mBaseUrl = context.getString(if (BuildConfig.DEBUG) R.string.local_url else R.string.live_url)

    val loggingInterceptor = HttpLoggingInterceptor()
    loggingInterceptor.level = if (BuildConfig.DEBUG) HttpLoggingInterceptor.Level.BODY else HttpLoggingInterceptor.Level.NONE

    val okHttpClient = OkHttpClient.Builder()
            .readTimeout(120, TimeUnit.SECONDS)
            .writeTimeout(120, TimeUnit.SECONDS)
            .connectTimeout(120, TimeUnit.SECONDS)
            .addInterceptor(loggingInterceptor)
            //.addNetworkInterceptor(networkInterceptor)
            .build()

    return Retrofit.Builder().baseUrl(mBaseUrl)
            .client(okHttpClient)
            .addConverterFactory(GsonConverterFactory.create())
            .addCallAdapterFactory(RxJava2CallAdapterFactory.create())
            .build().create(WebService::class.java)

}

}
```

Also change in `AppComponent`

```
@Singleton
@Component(modules = arrayOf(ApplicationModule::class, ApiModule::class))
interface AppComponent {
...

fun apiService(): WebService

...
}
```

your changes

```
@Component(modules = arrayOf(AndroidInjectionModule::class, AppModule::class, ApiModule ::class))
```

*add APIModule in relevant sub modules also*

**UPDATE**

```
@Component(modules = arrayOf(AndroidInjectionModule::class, AppModule::class, ActivityBuilder::class))
@Singleton
interface AppComponent {
fun inject(app: PartnerApplication)
fun apiService(): ApiHelper 
}
```

and then inject whenever you want to use.

```
@Inject
var webService: WebService? = null
```

Comment: I have two methods as of now in `doServerLoginApiCall` which returns `Observable<LoginResponse>` and `doServerRegistrationApiCall` which returns `Observable<RegistrationResponse>` in `ApiHelperImpl`. I couldn't understand what changes I have to make in my code. can you show with few more line of code thank you

Comment: I updated my question, can you please check it again

Comment: What is `WebService` and how to inject `apiService()`

Comment: WebService is your interface class where your GET,POST methods are declared. Use `ApiHelper ` instead of WebService. and inject in your ApiHelper Implementation.

Comment: Inject where in ApiHelper? Constructor ?

Comment: Thank you so much. I will try your solution.

Comment: Problem is not to initialize ApiHelperImpl. I am doing it like `ApiHelperImpl()` but it crashes when it tries to use `retrofit` there. it is not getting initialized, though I injected it there

Comment: @Williams I suggest you to go for dagger 2.10 implementation because for dagger 2.11 & 2.12, you won't be able to find proper documentation in Kotlin. Still, I tried but I will implement my own then only I can provide a proper solution.